# Independent reactions are interacting in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm using the `sliderInput` function with the animate argument to perform an automatic calculation in my shinyApp. However, using `animate` is affecting other reactions in my app. I would like to stop this side effect that is occurring in other reactivities.

For example, I have a `dropdownMenu` inside an `if` `else` structure. But, because of the `animate` argument, I can't click the option in the top right corner when I start the animation. It is disappearing with each calculation that the animate is doing. See:

[image]

I tried use `isolate()` in `pred_1()` but it stop the `valueBox` and the conditional structure (`if` `else` structure).

I'd like to just make `animate` not affect other reactivity in the app.

My app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  
  title = "Dashboard", 
  titleWidth = 300, 
  
  dropdownMenuOutput(
    outputId = "drop1"
  )
  
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  
  width = 300
  
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "one", 
    label = "Registro 1", 
    value = 1, 
    animate = animationOptions(
      interval = 500, loop = TRUE
    ),  
    min = 1, 
    max = 10, 
    step = 1, 
    ticks = TRUE
  ), 
  
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "two",
    label = "Registro 2", 
    value = 1, 
    animate = animationOptions(
      interval = 500, loop = TRUE
    ),  
    min = 1, 
    max = 10, 
    step = 1, 
    ticks = TRUE
  ), 
  
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "three", 
    label = "Sum 3", 
    value = 1, 
    animate = animationOptions(
      interval = 500, loop = TRUE
    ),  
    min = 1, 
    max = 10, 
    step = 1, 
    ticks = TRUE
  ), 
  
  valueBoxOutput(
    outputId = "box1"
  )
  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  header = header, 
  sidebar = sidebar, 
  body = body
  
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  fx <- function(x, y) {
    
    x + y
    
  }
  
  fy <- function(x) {
    
    x
    
  }
  
  reac_0 <- reactive({
    
    tibble::tibble(
      one = input$one, 
      two = input$two, 
      three = input$three
    )
    
  })
  
  chuveiro <- reactive({
    
    temp <- reac_0()
    fx(
      x = temp$one, 
      y = temp$two
    )
    
  })
  
  luz <- reactive({
    
    temp <- reac_0()
    fy(
      x = temp$three
    )
    
  })
  
  fdrop <- function(x) {
    
    if (x <= 5) {
        
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "notifications",
        badgeStatus = NULL,
        headerText = "Not 1", 
        notificationItem(
          text = HTML(
            "<text style='color:#020202;'>Without.</text>"
          ),
          status = "danger",
          icon = icon("times"),
          href = NULL
        )
      )
      
    } else (
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "notifications",
        badgeStatus = "danger",
        headerText = "Not 2", 
        notificationItem(
          text = HTML(
            "<a style='color:#020202;'
          href='https://www.instagram.com' target='_blank' title='A'>
          With</a>"
          ),
          status = "success",
          icon = icon("tags")
        )
      )
    )
  }
  
  output$drop1 <- renderMenu({
    
    expr = fdrop(x = luz())
    
  })
  
  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    
    expr = valueBox(
      value = chuveiro(), 
      subtitle = "Sum"
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So how can I make one reactivity effect another in a `shinyApp`?

I would like to click normally on the dropdownMenu notification with the `sliderInput` working with `animate`.

I tried isolating each argument of `sliderInput`, but not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reac0()` reactive is triggered whenever an input changes. Then it triggers every reactive that includes it, even if the value used in that reactive has not changed.

Your code :

```
reac_0 <- reactive({
  tibble::tibble(
    one = input$one, 
    two = input$two, 
    three = input$three
  )
})
 
luz <- reactive({
  temp <- reac_0()
  fy(
    x = temp$three
  )
})
```

triggers `luz()` whenever `one`, `two` or `three` changes.

An alternative would be to use `input$three` directly:

```
luz <- reactive({
  fy(
    x = input$three
  )
})
```

This way, the change or animation of slider `one` and `two` won't trigger `luz()` which won't trigger the menu rendering.

Of course, since the value of slider `three` is used to render the menu, any update of its value has to trigger the menu rendering.